# singleton pattern in storm topology

Tags: java, singleton, apache-storm

I have written a storm topology, and set its workers number to 1. 
So, I think all of its components should be run in the same process. And I want to share a common object between multiple components in the topology, so I use singleton pattern:
1, I initialize the singleton object when the unique spout has been opened.
2, Then, I use the singleton object in other components by calling the function getInstance().

But, I found that I will get the different objects between different components.

Thanks for your replies. The key code of the problem are listed as follows:
The singleton class code:

```
public class TraceApplicationContext {
   private volatile static TraceApplicationContext instance = new TraceApplicationContext();
   private TraceApplicationContext() {

   }
   public static TraceApplicationContext getInstance() {
        return instance;
   }
}
```

The SpoutA class code:

```
public class SpoutA extends BaseRichSpout {
    public void open(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, SpoutOutputCollector spoutOutputCollector) {
        TraceApplicationContext.getInstance().init();
    }
}
```

The BoltA code:

```
public class BoltA extends BaseRichBolt {
   private static JedisCluster jedisCluster   = TraceApplicationContext.getInstance().getJedisCluster();
}
```

The BoltB code:

```
public class BoltB extends BaseRichBolt {
   private static JedisCluster jedisCluster   = TraceApplicationContext.getInstance().getJedisCluster();
}
```

After initialized the TraceApplicationContext singleton object in SpoutA, I check the object return by TraceApplicationContext.getInstance().getJedisCluster(), it's not null. But I check it in BoltA and BoltB, the object returned by TraceApplicationContext.getInstance().getJedisCluster() is null.

Have anyone met the same problem or know what's wrong with such problem?

Please help!
Thank you!

Comment: Please show some code or we won't be able to help.

Comment: I have added my key code, please help. Thanks!

Comment: One thing to double-check is whether `TraceApplicationContext.class.getClassLoader()` returns the same class loader instance in all contexts. Any singleton is scoped to its class loader, not the entire JVM.

Comment: Using a singleton in storm can be tricky. Think that it is in most cases a singleton per class-loader (per JVM worker) and not a singleton for all the cluster. Also, sharing objects between bolts / spouts in a storm cluster is discouraged (locks, thread-safety, mutability...), if possible I think it is best to remove any use of singleton within storm.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't use enum as @Jorge_B says you can use a synchronized block in the `getInstance()` method

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static volatile MySingleton instance;
    private MySingleton() { ... }
    public static MySingleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null) {
            synchronized(MySingleton.class) {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = new MySingleton();
                }
            }
        }
        return instance;
    }
}
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern

---

EDIT

But it's may be not a singleton problem

The fact that the `getJedisCluster()` return different values doesn't mean that it's not the same singleton but rather that the state of the singleton has changed

try to make the `jedisCluster` final inside the singleton (a final property couldn't be changed but must be initialized inside the constructor)

```
private final JedisCluster jedisCluster;
```

if you can't try to track when the jedisCluster is changed : use of setter...

Answer (score 1):

If you have made sure all your processes run in the same JVM, try to implement your Singleton as an `Enumeration` of a single element.  This should solve every possible concurrence problem with the object initialization.

For example:

An implementation like

```
public class MySingleton {
   private static MySingleton instance;
   private MySingleton() { ... }
   public static MySingleton getInstance() {
      if (instance == null) { instance = new MySingleton() }
      return instance;
   }
}
```

Is prone to concurrency problems.  However, one like this

```
public enum MySingleton {
   INSTANCE;

   private MySingleton() {...}
}
```

Should work everywhere.

Comment: +1, the problem with OPs code is he is trying to call an init() method in his spout. Creating the instance should be handled inside the Singleton automatically.

Answer (score 0):

As with my experience, I was using singleton cassandra session object, as well as singleton for application properties in my storm topology.
Since these singleton objects do not have any varying state , even when we have multiple WorkerProcess(WP) (ie one JVM per WP), each WP will have a copy of the singleton and can be made use without issue.

As far as best practice is concerned, its better to set the static singletons to the config object while submitting the topology, and the prepare method will supply it to individual tasks.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/rWeQpGEnT9Q